# SharePoint Online - Communication Sites: Creating pages in different site pages library fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, settings

I created a document library on a Communications Site and wanted to use it to  store pages and prevent the default library to be crowded with unrelated pages.
In the new library I reset the default content type to "web site" and removed the document content type. Now when I click "New" and select "web site" a site is being created, but in `/SitePages` instead of my new library.
Is this intended behavior? Is there a setting or a workaround?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the “web site” content type is a custom content type which “site page” content type as its parent content type?

In that case, it’s the default behavior that it links to edit page in SitePages library when we create a new page with this content type in the new document library.

As a workaround, you can create a new content type which its parent content type is “Basic Page”. Or you can move the relevant pages to new document library and delete these pages SitePages library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not working. It does not matter if I use "Basic Page" oder inherit from it - it throws an error after creating the page in the library.

Comment: what's the error when you create the page in library?

Comment: The page is created, it can't find some webpart when I open the page. Also the created page is not in the modern UX style.

Comment: Yes, there is no web part and modern UI style in the "Basic page" style page. So i recommend you moving the site pages from SitePages library to document library if you want to use the modern UI style page.

Comment: I maybe got you wrong, but this is what I wanted to achieve. And it does not work. I guess it is not meant to be as of now. Thanks for your help.